# Kottwitz global gerbes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, galois-representations, gerbes

I've been trying to understand global gerbes constructed by Kottwitz in *$B(G)$ for all local and global fields* (arXiv:[1401.5728](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.5728)). Scholze explained in *$p$-adic geometry* (arXiv:[1712.03708](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.03708)) why I would be interested in these. However, I find Kottwitz article fairly hard to read. In particular, it is hard for me to relate the notation in Scholze's article to Kottwiz's notation. Does anyone know a nice reference for Kottwitz's construction of global gerbes, or would care to sketch it for me?

Comment: I don't think there is any other reference. But it might be useful to try to understand $B(G)$ for a connected reductive group $G/\mathbb{Q}_p$ in terms of morphisms from the the Dieudonné gerb $\mathfrak{D} \to \mathfrak{G}_{G}$, where $\mathfrak{G}_{G}$ is the neutral $\mathbb{Q}_p^{\text{ur}}/\mathbb{Q}_p$ gerb associated to $G$. This is explained on page 109 and 110 of Reiman's book 'the semi-simple zeta function of quaternionic Shimura varieties'. See also the remark on page 86 of Langlands-Rapoport.